# Why is dhclient + systemd-resolved restarting frequently?

Tags: networking, dns, display-resolution, dhcp, systemd-resolved

I'm running an ubuntu server in aws on VERSION="18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)"

We've been having intermittent dns resolution issues, and while looking into that I've seen that every 20 minutes or so I'm seeing the following in syslog

```
Mar 19 00:17:03 localhost dhclient[815]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.26.85 on eth0 to 172.31.16.1 port 67 (xid=0x7d329bb3)
Mar 19 00:17:03 localhost dhclient[815]: DHCPACK of 172.31.26.85 from 172.31.16.1
Mar 19 00:17:03 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Mar 19 00:17:03 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Mar 19 00:17:03 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Mar 19 00:17:04 localhost dhclient[815]: bound to 172.31.26.85 -- renewal in 1747 seconds.
```

It seems every time dhclient goes through a renewal process it causes systemd-resolved to restart, which momentarily makes dns resolution not work.  So if some process was running at that time, the resolution may fail.

I'm not really sure where to begin on this.  Is it normal for dhclient to cause systemd-resolved to restart so frequently? What's the right solution to this issue?  Should I force dhclient to renew much less frequently, does that have some negative impact? Any other suggestions?

Comment: *"renewal in 1747 seconds"* suggests maybe the network's DHCP server is configured to offer ~30 minute lease durations?

Comment: Looks like a poor DCHP implementation in the seever. This is unluckily very common on plastic routers. You might want to try to manually configure the DNS servers.

Comment: By any chance did you upgrade your instance from pre-18? So far, I've tracked this issue down to only occur when having upgraded from 17.04 or earlier (meaning an upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 might still exhibit this behavior)

Comment: @dwanderson I actually DID upgrade these instances from pre-18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the `dhclient` renewal (especially because the default lease-time in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` is `#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;` aka 1 hour), but the `DNS` resolution errors seems to be a consequence of this renewal triggering a `systemd-resolved` restart.

I confirmed this in my own case by running

```
sudo grep -Pi '(renewal|started network name)' /var/log/syslog | tail
```

which showed that `systemd` would restart after the renewal time had elapsed. Also, I noticed that `ps -ef | grep [r]esolv` showed that the `systemd-resolved` process never ran fro more than 30 minutes, while other servers had this process run for weeks at a time.

After much googling and scouring and confusion, I came across a patch [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/402306173/0001-making-it-work-on-aws-ec2.patch):

```
--- /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved.orig  2018-12-20 22:16:45.914466953 +0000
+++ /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolved   2018-12-20 23:15:03.861114407 +0000
@@ -26,10 +26,13 @@
               if [ ! "$interface" ] ; then
                   return
               fi
               statedir="/run/systemd/resolved.conf.d"
               mkdir -p $statedir
+
+              oldstate="$(mktemp)"
+              md5sum $statedir/isc-dhcp-v4-$interface.conf $statedir/isc-dhcp-v6-$interface.conf > $oldstate 2>&1
               if [ -n "$new_domain_name_servers" ] ; then
                   cat <<EOF >$statedir/isc-dhcp-v4-$interface.conf
 [Resolve]
 DNS=$new_domain_name_servers
 EOF
@@ -48,11 +51,19 @@
                       cat <<EOF >>$statedir/isc-dhcp-v6-$interface.conf
 Domains=$new_dhcp6_domain_search
 EOF
                   fi
               fi
-              systemctl try-reload-or-restart systemd-resolved.service
+
+              newstate="$(mktemp)"
+              md5sum $statedir/isc-dhcp-v4-$interface.conf $statedir/isc-dhcp-v6-$interface.conf > $newstate 2>&1
+              if ! cmp --quiet $oldstate $newstate; then
+                  systemctl try-reload-or-restart systemd-resolved.service
+              fi
+
+              rm $oldstate
+         rm $newstate
           }
                 ;;

           EXPIRE|FAIL|RELEASE|STOP)
               if [ ! "$interface" ] ; then
```

which I then installed on my server(s) by saving it into `some-file` and then running `sudo patch <some-file`

For good measure, I rebooted my server, not sure if that's required.